# How can I load grails plugins from a custom artifactory repo?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, artifactory

Grails 2.3.10

I have authored a Grails plugin for use within my company and installed in on the company's Artifactory repo. How can I set up another project's BuildConfig so that it checks the company's private artifactory repo when installing plugins?

Here is what I have tried:

```
repositories {
    ...
    grailsRepo "http://artifactory.mycompany.com/"
}
```

and also...

```
repositories {
    ...
    mavenRepo "http://artifactory.mycompany.com/"
}
```

Neither of these seem to have any effect. What's the correct config to change or add to the grails plugins repo?

Ideally, I would like both the custom repo and the grails central repo to be checked for plugins.

**Edit:**

To clarify further... I want my project configured to pull down a plugin that only exists on the company's artifactory server, not on the central Grails plugin repo.

I get the following output from grails compile:

```
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:cascade-validation:zip:0.1.0 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:cascade-validation:zip:0.1.0 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:cascade-validation:zip:0.1.0 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:cascade-validation:zip:0.1.0 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
```

It looks like the company server is not being accessed based on the build output.

Comment: mavenRepo is sufficient for a "web based" repo.  are you sure, you have put the plugin in `plugins{}` and not `dependencies{}`.  is there an error?  does `--verbose` and/or `--debug` give better errors?

Comment: what `grails.project.dependency.resolver` are you using?

Comment: @cfrick: It's set to "maven".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I do it. The plugin's BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.dependency.distribution = {
    remoteRepository(id: "localPluginReleases", url: "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release-local/")
    remoteRepository(id: "localPluginSnapshots", url: "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot-local/")
}
```

The plugin is then packaged with:

```
grails publish-plugin --allow-overwrite --noScm --repository=localPluginReleases
```

The app's BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot-local/"
        mavenRepo "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release-local/"
        //  other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I put the mavenRepo first, I no longer see it hitting grails central. Is there a way I can get it to check both places? Also... when I use the publish-plugin command I get this error: "No configuration found for repository 'true'"

Comment: How do you know it's not hitting grails central? If your other plugins are up to date, it won't download anything. I usually `cd /path/to/my/app` (not plugin) and `rm -r target` and then `grails compile` to ensure the app gets the latest update. I'm not sure about your publishing error. Did you put the correct URL in the plugin's BuildConfig.groovy? I just installed artifactory on my dev box and used the default settings.

Comment: @RMorrisey did you find the answer to this? I am unable to publish the plugin and I have the correct url and the dependency distribution in the BuildConfig.groovy as stated above

Comment: @Viriato: I moved my plugin to the central repo so I don't do this anymore in my project... but if I recall correctly, Ken's reply comment above solved my issue. I also remember having a case where I was trying to configure the plugin as a dependency in the project section instead of the plugin section of BuildConfig... you might check and see if you're hitting that, also. In addition, be sure you install the plugin artifact to the correct path... Grails plugins are expected to be pathed under /org/grails/plugins/(plugin-name).

Comment: @RMorrisey I removed the dependency.distribution as in the Programming Grails book example that I was following and replaced it with this and it works
grails.project.repos.myRepo.url = "http://serverRoot/artifactory/plugins-release-local/"

grails.project.repos.default = "myRepo"

grails.project.repos.myRepo.type = "maven"

grails.project.repos.myRepo.username = "admin"

grails.project.repos.myRepo.password = "password"